# Datepicker in a td on click, after losing focus, the selected value should get set in the table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
function dateFieldShow (elem,rowInd,colInd){
    var OriginalContent =$(elem).text();
    $(elem).empty();
    $("<input type='text' size='10' name='something' class='dateFilter'>").val(OriginalContent).appendTo($(elem)).focus();
}

$('body').on('focus',".dateFilter", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: "../Img/btnCal.bmp",
        buttonImageOnly :true
        //showButtonPanel :true,
    })
})
```

This function `dateFieldShow` is been called when I click a `td` with my particular class. Where input element has `class="dateFilter"` which is a datepicker.

Now the element is created as such `<td><input><img></img></input></td>`.

What I want is that after the element is typed in input or the the `td` loses focus/blur which has these two elements. I want the selected value of datepicker `value=$(".dateFilter").datepicker("getDate");` to set back in `('#maingrid').DataTable().cell( rowInd, colInd ).data( value);`

Only when the input element loses focus, the above should happen, not on `onSelect` or `onClose` function.

This is something similar to ExtJs grid editing, I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The function you show has no name, is it supposed to be `dateFieldShow`? Edit your question and fix that. It is hard to understand your question, but one issue I see is that you are re-initialising your datepicker every time the field gets focus - you should initialise it just once.  Does the code you've shown work? What happens?

Comment: I need to initialize it for all the rows every time the td i clicked i need to show the datepicker